# Como denominar o 3º nível de uma aba?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Em uma situação em que há três níveis de abas em uma tela de programa:

> 1º nível: Aba Animais
>   2º nível: Subaba Mamíferos
>   3º nível: _____ Cães

Como posso denominar esse terceiro nível para citá-lo em um documento, considerando que está dentro de subaba?
Por exemplo:

[image]

Comment: Talvez sua pergunta seja mais apropriada ao SE computational science.

Comment: Lissandra, Não estou inteiramente seguro de compreender o que são essas abas: isso podia ser um menu? Clicas em *Departamento* e aparece um outro menu para escolher entre *setor 1, setor 2*, etc; clicas setor 2 e aparece outro menu com *marca X, marca Y*, etc.?. Não podes pôr uma figura ou link onde se veja claramente aquilo a que te referes. De qualquer modo substituí o tag para «palavra-para-ideia», que é de facto o que tu pedes.

Comment: *Subsubaba* soa muito mal. Não sei se *subaba de setor 2* serve?

Comment: Eu trocaria "setor" por "nível" e usaria algo parecido com o que o @Jacinto propôs.

Comment: @eightShirt Se calhar estamos a pensar em coisas diferentes. Parece-me que estás a propôr *subaba de nível 2* como terminologia universal? Eu estava a fazer uma sugestão só para este exemplo: o «setor 2» tem uma subaba «marca» ou várias subabas, cada uma para uma marca, e o «setor 1» também. Do mesmo modo se tivermos 1º nível «Animais», 2º nível «mamíferos», «aves», etc., 3º nível dentro dos «mamíferos», «cães», «gatos», etc., então «cães» é uma subaba de «mamíferos», «mamíferos» é uma subaba de «animais», etc. Não sei se isto serve para alguma coisa, mas era o que eu estava a pensar.

Comment: Alguns programas chamam as abas de guias, como nos navegadores de internet o Mozilla Firefox chama de Aba e o Google Chrome de Guia. E acredito que a palavra subaba não possa existir pois sub e aba são pronunciados separadamente, talvez sub-aba.

Comment: Ele quer identificar os níveis através do nome dado para a Aba. Geralmente o que se faz é identificar apenas o tipo de estrutura, por exemplo aba_Dep, aba_Setor, e muitas vezes aproveitando os nomes em inglês mesmo tab_Dep. Mas uma saída é numerar cada nivel assim ou parecido com isso:.aba1_dep, aba11_setor, aba111_ marca, aba112_modelo, aba12_outro_seg_nivel, aba121_outro_terceiro_nivel

Comment: O que preciso é referenciar essa aba de terceiro nível em um documento que explicará sua funcionalidade.

Comment: @Lissandra você respondeu à sua questão, «aba de terceiro nível»

Comment: Sim, posso tratá-la dessa forma, mas gostaria de saber se havia um termo específico para defini-la.

Comment: @AndréLyra, a palavra "subaba" é escrita dessa forma, pois segundo recomendação do novo acordo ortográfico da língua portuguesa é eliminado o hífen de palavras compostas pelo prefixo "sub" seguidas de palavras que iniciam com vogais.

http://www.abril.com.br/reforma-ortografica/hifen.shtml

Comment: Em pt-PT fala-se su-ba-lu-gar para justificar isso? Entendo que algumas coisas do idioma aceitamos e decoramos, talvez por costume as pessoas nem percebam que a pronúncia sub-a-lu-gar é forçada.

Comment: @Lissandra, usando aba de nível três ou aba de terceiro nível fica bastante compreensível.

Comment: Minha opinião subjetiva é que até mesmo "subaba" já não funciona bem. No exemplo que você deu, por que não chamar todas as abas de "abas", simplesmente? Nenhuma repete o nome em níveis diferentes. Se houvesse uma aba "Animais" no terceiro nível, por exemplo, seria necessário distinguir os níveis. Como não tem, você pode simplesmente dizer, em um texto, algo como "clique na aba 'Animais', depois na aba 'Mamíferos' e finalmente na aba 'Cães'." Se isso não funciona, pode nos dar um exemplo concreto do que você quer expressar?

Comment: Pode tentar Domesticos Selvagens

Comment: @brandizzi as abas podem ser dinâmicas, e depender de *input* de utilizador. Talvez a Lissandra esteja a fazer um documento em que não sabe o conteúdo das abas, e "animais" seja... um exemplo.

Comment: @AndréLyra a pronúncia "sub·a·lu·gar" é tão forçada como a pronúncia "muin·to" (em vez de "mui·to") ou a pronúncia "jói·a" (em vez de "jôi·a"). É assim e pronto. A língua portuguesa é muito traiçoeira... :(

Comment: Neste caso criou-se a forma su ba lu gar por canetada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subaba tem de ser relativa a uma aba. Indica que existe uma aba à qual ela "pertence" mas nada indica que nível em termos hierárquicos ela tem.

Usando o conceito do OP de nível, o 3º nível, é também uma subaba, mas da aba que a engloba.

Portanto, o 1º nível é uma aba que têm uma subaba "Mamíferos", que por sua vez tem uma subaba "Cães", e por aí fora. Não terá uma designação que indique que é uma subaba de uma subaba de uma aba "Animais".

Answer (score 3):

Como eu não tenho pontos suficientes ainda para comentar a pergunta, eu vou responder por aqui:

Se você for referenciar a ordem de navegação das abas em um documento escrito, eu costumo ver esse nível de identação de menus/abas escritas assim:

`(Vá na) Aba Animais > Mamíferos > Cães`

Onde o `>` indica o próximo nível de um elemento similar ao primeiro elemento citado (no caso, a aba). Eu digo isso pois imagino o caso de uma documentação de um software/manual, onde a pessoa tem visão logo de cara de que outras abas aparecem mais abaixo das abas principais, além do que no seu caso, para mim ao menos, seria intuitivo entender essa escrita com `>`.

Ou então, outra sugestão:

`Siga as abas "Animais", "Mamíferos" e (finalmente) "Cães"`. O "finalmente" é opcional dependendo da profundidade de aninhamento das abas e do estilo de escrita. Nesse caso, você apenas vai listando as várias abas possíveis até chegar na última que for de interesse.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria "aba de terceiro nível".

Se houver dois níveis de abas, diria "aba" e "sub-aba".
Mas havendo mais que dois, diria "aba", "aba de segundo nível", "aba de terceiro nível", etc.

Um pouco como nas secções de documentos.
Havendo dois níveis, eu diria "secção" e "sub-secção".
Mas havendo mais que dois, diria "secção", "secção de segundo nível", "secção de terceiro nível", etc.